How does the Heightened Spell metamagic work with long, multi-use spells like Eyebite or Telekinesis?
Heightened spell says that when you cast a spell which forces an enemy to roll a saving throw, they do that with disadvantage. What happens with "effect" spells like Telekinesis or Eyebite, where the spell does indeed forces a saving throw but not with its direct effect, instead when the player uses its effect after the casting. Both of these spells work by first activating their effect (ability to do telekinesis / a third eye) then the player can use these abilities through an action, which triggers the saving throw.
So
Is heightened spell completely unusable cause the casting itself triggers no rolls?
Or can it be applied on the first target?
In that case, could it be applied multiple times on that very same target, as heightened spell specifies that only one target of the spell is affected?
Or can the heightened spell be used on the action "parts" of these spells instead, again and again?

@ThomasMarkov - Immolation is a single target, repeated save.  Telekinesis is not a save.  Eyebite is multiple targets, with an initial save per target but three separate effects, only one of which then gets subsequent saves.  I think that OP needs to narrow the question to one  of the two spells he asked about, but neither one is going to be a duplicate of immolation.

Hi @oliver.c Telekinesis is not a save. Eyebite is multiple targets, with an initial save per target but three separate effects, only one of which then gets subsequent saves.  If you can choose one of these and edit your question to explain why it is different than the linked question, it could be re-opened.  Let us know if the linked question purported to be a duplicate does not answer your own question.
